# How can I use wildcards with string::find?

Tags: c++, wildcard

I want to be able to use a wildcard in `string::find` and then fetch what was in that wildcard place.

For example:

```
if (string::npos !=input.find("How is * doing?")
{
     cout<<"(the wildcard) is doing fine."<<endl;
}
```

And so if I ask, "How is Mom doing?", the output would be "Mom is doing fine."

What libraries would I use for this, or how would I write the code manually? If I should use AIML, can AIML execute .bat files?

Comment: C++ is not high-level enough to achieve this without some kind of library

Comment: What you're doing seems more like AIML

Comment: You will either need to write the code to do this manually, or use a regular-expression library.

Comment: writing a code manually for your case shouldn't be tough i suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your question on how to do it manually, i will give you an idea with this simple code, which solves the example which you gave in the question.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string expr="How is * doing?";
    string input="How is Mom doing?";
    int wildcard_pos=expr.find("*");
    if(wildcard_pos!=string::npos)
    {
        int foo=input.find(expr.substr(0,wildcard_pos)),bar=input.find(expr.substr(wildcard_pos+1));
        if(foo!=string::npos && bar!=string::npos)
        cout<<input.substr(wildcard_pos,bar-wildcard_pos)<<" is doing fine\n";
    }
}
```

You can easily modify this idea to suit your needs. Else, follow the answer given by `src`

Answer (score 5):

C++ 2011 provides a [regular expression library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Regular_expressions). If you can't use C++ 2011 yet you can use the [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library or any C library like [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).