# Handling a 'wildcard' character in C++

Tags: c++

I need a function to identify a pattern string within another string while taking into consideration a wildcard character `_`

For instance, if the given pattern is `f__h`, then it should match up to the string `catfish`.

So essentially, the underscore needs to be able to represent any alphabetical character, but I can't think of a way to go about this. Anyone got some ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276000/how-can-i-use-wildcards-with-stringfind

Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
std::search(
    text.begin(), text.end(),
    pattern.begin(), pattern.end(),
    []( char fromText, char fromPattern ) {
        return fromPattern == '_' || fromPattern == fromText;
    } )
```

If the function returns `text.end()`, there was no match.
Otherwise, it returns an iterator to the first character of the
match.

Answer (score 3):

With new standard C++11 you can use [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). Otherwise use [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: A bit overkill for something that simple, no?  (If there were other meta characters, or anything required variable length, I'd agree.  But in this case, just using `std::search` with a simple predicate is simpler than mapping his search string to a regular expression.)

Comment: Maybe, but since now is a standard C++ feature, I don't think that's convenient to find other non standard solutions or give same (or more effort) to find a solution valid for this particular case: std::search is an alternative, of course, but between different approaches this is my personal choice.

Comment: std::search is another standard alternative. in my previous sentence one can understand the opposite... sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm a great fan of regular expressions, but in this case: the OP seems to have been given a required format, which isn't compatible with standard regular expressions.  So in order to use `regex`, he would first have to translate his input into a standard regular expression.  Which is not necessarily trivial: he has to map `_` to `.`, but also to escape any other `regex` meta-characters.  If the pattern language is complicated (e.g. with closures), it's probably the best solution, but for something this simple, using `std::search` is simpler than the translation.

Comment: This has the downside that you need to find a *conforming* compiler (and not all of them are...), with `std::search` it works very nicely...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a C-style solution, this works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * wildcard_strstr(const char * haystack, const char * needle)
{
   int needleLen = strlen(needle);
   while(*haystack)
   {
      const char * needleP   = needle;
      const char * haystackP = haystack;

      bool match = true;
      while((*needleP)&&(*haystackP)&&((*needleP == *haystackP)||(*needleP == '_')))
      {
         needleP++;
         haystackP++;
      }
      if ((needleP-needle) == needleLen) return haystack;
                                    else haystack++;
   }
   return NULL;
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   while(1)
   {
      char haystack[512];
      printf("Input haystack: "); fflush(stdout);
      fgets(haystack, sizeof(haystack), stdin);
      haystack[strlen(haystack)-1] = '\0';  // trim newline

      char needle[512];
      printf("Input needle: "); fflush(stdout);
      fgets(needle, sizeof(needle), stdin);
      needle[strlen(needle)-1] = '\0';  // trim newline

      const char * match = wildcard_strstr(haystack, needle);
      printf("\nNeedle [%s] %s in haystack [%s]\n", needle, match?"IS":"IS NOT", haystack);
      if (match) printf("  returned match position is %p [%s]\n", match, match);
   }
}
```